# Windows saying it's PM when it's AM

Tags: windows, windows-10, time

In Windows 10, the clock is saying its 12:08 PM when it's 12:08 AM (noon).
The bios clock is 24 hour format as is correct (12:08).
I have the time zone set correctly (I'm in UK so its UTC+00:00).
I have automatic timezone and automatic time set to enabled.

I am not sure how to fix this without diving into the registry but I think I should probably fix it as it can confuse me and lead to system instability.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: Maybe it is saying it is 12:00 PM because it is at least 1 minute past, however I could be wrong and it is still confusing to me

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, `12:08 AM` is midnight, not noon. Also, please have a look at the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: I think it's correct and you're confusing it. Noon is 12 o'clock so any time after it is PM.

Comment: You are confused but Wikipedia isn't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noon . However, your confusion does not and can not translate to "system instability". If you have an issue please ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems correct.

`12:00 AM` is actually midnight, which goes up to `11:59 AM` (noon), then after one minute, it goes to `12:00 PM` (noon) till `11:59 PM` (just before midnight).

You can type in the command prompt:

```
time
```

which would give for example:

```
C:\>time
The current time is: 13:29:57.30
Enter the new time:
```

Comment: It is easier to explain that the 12th hour is displayed as 0:00 on devices that use a 24h format, because time goes from 0:00 till 11:59. This also explains why 12:00 AM (or rather 0:00 AM) is midnight.